# Node JS wait for series of mysql queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, asynchronous

I'm developing a RESTful API using mysql and Node JS. I wrapped my queries to the database in the select function defined as:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var db = mysql.createConnection({
host     : CONFIG.db_host,
user     : CONFIG.db_user,
password : CONFIG.db_password,
database : CONFIG.db_name
});

function select(query, callback, out, args) 
{
    console.log('Sent query: ' + query);
    db.query(query, args, function(err, rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        return callback(rows, out);
    });
};
```

In order to implement one feature in my application, I have to perform a query on a database table that returns an undetermined number of rows (N), and use the information obtained in each of these rows in order to perform N new queries on another table.

Something like:

```
function callback(rows, out){

    // just to give the idea ...

    for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
    {
       db.select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=?", function(rows, out){
           out.push(rows);
       }, rows[i].col)
    }  
    // wait for all queries ...

    console.log(out)
}

out = []
db.select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=?", callback, out, col)
```

There is no problem in running all the queries asynchronously, but I have to wait for all of them to be over before returning the response of my API. I figured using Promises could be the way, but given the undetermined number of queries I didn't get how to implement it. Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe you should used NoSQL instead because SQL has blocking operations.

Comment: I argue that this question in its current form is too broad. Do you want to use promises but don't know how? Are you trying to figure out if to use promises at all? I recommend digging deeper on what you don't understand about promises and ask a question about that.

Comment: Instead of using `mysql` you may want to have a look at `promise-mysql` or `knex`. Those already wrap the database interaction in promises so you don't have to.

Comment: As far as I understood in order to use promises I have to define them in advance. In my case I could, for instance, wrap my sql queries in the form of a promise and use the *then* method in order to make sure they are done before doing anything else. My issue here is that I don't know how many promises I would have to define in advance, nor I do know how to define a single promise that would wait for all the queries to be over. I will have a look at the libraries you recommend though! thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is the `for` loop. Using it means you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code.

If you need to use the callback pattern, I recommend you also use an external library such as [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) that makes it easier to use asynchronous iteration patterns. Something like the following would probably do the trick:

```
var async = require('async');

conn.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=?', col, function (err, rows) {
    async.each(rows, function (row, callback) {
        conn.query('SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE col=?', row.col, callback);
    }, function () {
        // all queries are done
    })
});
```

If you want to use promises instead, the [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) package provide a similar API to [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), but with support for [promises](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md). The interesting thing with a `Promise`-based API is that you can then use `async/await` (on Node.js `>= 7.6`), which makes your life a lot easier if you don't really like the asynchronous nature of regular JavaScript code.

So, in your case, you would be able to do something like:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

async function main () {
    var conn = await mysql.createConnection({
        host     : CONFIG.db_host,
        user     : CONFIG.db_user,
        password : CONFIG.db_password,
        database : CONFIG.db_name
    });

    var [rows] = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=?', col);
    var out = [];

    for (var row of rows) {
        var result = await db.query('SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE col=?', row.col);
        out.push(result);
    }

    // all queries are done
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks ruiquelhas! I will definitely run it the way you indicated!